# YA/Children’s ghost story anthology book

Tags: story-identification, books, ghost, anthology-book

I’ve been searching for this book for years but we shall see.
I read a horror anthology book targeted for children (I read it in elementary school) and need the title. I cannot remember much of the stories but I do know the topic of two.

The first one was about a Nantucket sleigh ride. A girl is reading Moby Dick and her uncle notices. He informs her of what Nantucket sleigh rides are and elaborate on the dangers of them.
The end of the story reveals he is a ghost and has rope burns on his wrists (from a Nantucket sleigh ride).

Another story was about a couple stopping at a gas station on a road trip. Someone goes to the outhouse and is transported to a new world. They watch a sort of native American battle unfold.

The cover featured a native american from the aforementioned story. The book is likely from the 70s-80s.

Comment: There is an anthology of three novellas called [Nantucket Slayrides](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?23396) that has a picture of what I guess could be a native American shaman on the cover. But it doesn't look like a children's book.

Comment: @JohnRennie - that book appears to be a memoir.  It does mention another book, The Ghosts of Nantucket, which tells 23 purportedly true accounts of ghost stories.  I have read neither of the books though.

Comment: Kayla, welcome to the site!  I hope you enjoy participating.

Comment: @kayla This might be a book I've been trying to find as well. Do you remember it having stories about a haunted carousel and the ghost of a pirate?

Answer (score 2):

*Shadows and whispers: tales from the other side* by Collin McDonald contains *Nantucket sleigh ride* which matches the description of the first story.
It can be read on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/shadowswhisperst00mcdo).

Comment: The second story doesn't seem to fit anything else in that book though. Maybe "Souvenir" partially.